# Usage of sendAction:to:from:forEvent:?

Tags: ios, uikit

`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]` method looks interesting. Is there any usage utilizes this method greatly?

Comment: Please consider marking my answer as accepted.

Comment: @jemmons Thanks for the answer. But it's hard to find the text you mention. Can I have a link?

Comment: [Here you go](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html)

Answer (score 2):

Read up on the "responder chain" pattern in Cocoa. Calling this method (with `nil` for the  `to:` parameter) is how iOS apps post actions to that chain.